# Guidelines for vs Guidelines to

Tags: prepositions

Could you please explain to me the difference between `Guidelines for` and `Guidelines to`?

Comment: I am developing guidelines **for** doing XYZ.  When I've completed the task, I'll give the guidelines **to** my boss.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a particular example?

Personally I would use "guidelines for" in most situations, when referring to whatever the guidelines are for. *"Please see guidelines for using the pool" "follow these guidelines for gram staining" "Here are the guidelines for evacuation"* In all of these scenarios 'to' wouldn't sound right (though I can't pinpoint why).

I would use 'to' in the same way fixer1234 has commented, showing movement/transferal of the guidelines and i'm sure there are other contexts it would fit, this may be one of those times where English has too many rules and exceptions for most people to keep track of.

Answer (score 1):

Two sentences from [Britannica Dictionary](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/guideline)

1. The government has issued new guidelines **for** following a healthy and balanced diet.
2. Here are some basic guidelines **for** helping you choose a dishwasher

Amongst 23 examplary sentences on [OALD](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/guideline?q=guideline) there isn't a sentence with 'guideline to something'.

I'm tempted to say that 'guideline on something' is another option. See the sentences on [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/tr/s%C3%B6zl%C3%BCk/ingilizce/guideline). So I usually prefer to write 'guideline **for** someone/something' and 'guideline **on** something'. Here are two examples from [LDOCE](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/guideline)

1. a new set of guidelines **for** teachers
2. guidelines **on** the employment of children

However, it would've been better if you'd provided a specific context/situation for your question.